# Exception #0 (Exception): Item (Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Status) with the same ID "1" already exists

Tags: magento2.2.3

Whenever we are clicking on a Product on Admin site, we are getting this Error.

```
    Exception #0 (Exception): Item (Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Status) with the same ID "1" already exists
```

[image]

Comment: Check duplicate entry in catalogInventory_stock_status table.

Comment: i already checked that. There is not duplicate entry. But there are 4-5 entries of each product but with different stock_id(1,2,3,4,5)

Comment: Take backup then remove Row number(2,3,4,7 and 8). Then try after reindex.

Comment: i deleted these records and then did the reindex.
Reindex again created those deleted record !!!
Still getting same error.

Answer (score 1):

It occurs when you have duplicated entries in your stock status collection.

If you customized the catalog/product page, try to debug your stock status collection, or turn on the mysql queries log and see if have duplicated ids in the last logged query.

Comment: Thanks @douglas-ianitsky
Please explain a bit in detail. It will help me to Resolve. I have also attached the pic of DB table catalogInventory_stock_status